# Is it possible to set the TLS version in app.config?

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2

I have a desktop application that uses web services (SharePoint).

Since I upgraded TLS to 1.2, I am getting this error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The code does not set the protocol programmatically, but it's quite old code, so I suspect it uses 1.1.

I am aware I can change that in the code, but before I do that I wanted to ask: is there any way I can set the protocol version in the app.config, and so avoid changing the code?

Below is the call stack, if it can help:

Thanks in advance.

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Some mode details:

Unfortunately I do know know what exactly was done, the upgrade was done by someone else, same for the version of .NET I do not know, 3.5 or later.

What I am asking is whether the setting shown below can be configured in the app.config, so that I do not need to re-compile to application:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: *Since I upgraded TLS to 1.2* Can you be more specific (e.g. did you run an installer, or do something manually)? Also, what version of .NET is it?

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the reply, I have added some more details to the post.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls Microsoft documented all. BTW, never guess what happened. Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze TLS handshakes and then the details should be obvious to you.

Comment: TLS is not supported on .NET 3.5 and there is no workaround. So I think you are stuck recompiling. [This link](https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/) may help.

Comment: Thank you both for you replies, "I think you are stuck recompiling" is the way to go. It was worth a try.